# Why did Wong say "Attachment to the material is detachment from the spiritual"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War (2018)*, Doctor Strange and Wong step down stairs:

> Doctor Strange: Seriously, you don't have any money?
>
> Wong: **Attachment to the  material is detachment from the spiritual**.
>
> Doctor Strange: I'll tell the guys at the deli. Maybe they'll make you a metaphysical ham on rye.

Comment: That's probably just a reference to [asceticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asceticism), which is common among monks

Comment: writing this at 12:03, this is making me hungry, better go get a metaphysical sandwich

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He is just expressing the converse of the philosophy of [detachment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detachment_(philosophy)).

Per the Wikipedia entry:

> Detachment, also expressed as non-attachment, is a state in which a person overcomes his or her attachment to desire for things, people or concepts of the world and thus attains a heightened perspective. It is considered a wise virtue and is promoted in various Eastern religions, such as Jainism, Taoism and Buddhism.

It is a cornerstone of asceticism and similar practices that there is a tradeoff between the amount of attention someone pays to the physical world around them and their inner spiritual world.  This is the reason for the existence of religious hermits and cloistered orders of monks.  By spending less time on the material world, these people hope to achieve a higher spiritual consciousness.  Wong is expressing the inverse implication, that being too engrossed in the physical world distracts someone from their spiritual calling.